# Importing excel file with swapped date formats python

Tags: pandas

I have an excel file where the data starts with format MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss, later after few entries it switches back to DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss. This sequence happens a couple of times in the data set. Is there a way to import this into python? The convert to datetime by specifying format doesn't work because there are different formats.

The dataframe looks like this:

[image: The dataframe looks like this.]

Comment: Nope, this isn't a duplicate (possibly too broad, needs a [mcve]). OP needs to specify start and end rows for each region where you have dayfirst / standard convention. This needs to be supplied as an input. There's no way to programmatically resolve which way is correct.

Comment: I agree, so reopened.

Comment: Please supply a **[mcve]**. This means no images or links.

Comment: You need to come up with logic to detect when the dates switch. For example, "any time a row is over n days from the row above it, the date format has switched." You can then use that logic to split the data into parts, and convert each part to python datetimes individually. Or, there are may be an easier way to correct the dates ahead of time, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the datetimes are actual datetimes in Excel as well, re-format them first, and then read into Python. Select the whole column, open the format window (`CTRL + 1` on Windows), go to the "Number" panel, choose "Date," and then choose an appropriate format for your data.

With the dates all in the same format, now read the file into Python using pandas or another library.